# UTF8 strings partially not recognized

Tags: perl, unicode, mojolicious

When I fetch Cyrillic text from SQLite3 database, in some situations perl (or Mojolicious, or DBIx::Class - I honestly don't know) fails to decode bytestream. For example, given the text:

```
1984г1ф!!11четыре
```

output will be:

```
1984г1ф!!11������
1984\x{433}1\x{444}!!11\x{fffd}\x{fffd}\x{fffd}\x{fffd}\x{fffd}\x{fffd}
```

Why is this happening? How to fix this?

**Update:** I was able to trace the source of this issue. Looks like malformed string is taken from user input on a web-page, and dispatched to Controller action as a parameter: [code here](http://codepad.org/SKofssg0).

Executing save action produces the following log:

```
[2012/07/24 14:06:09] [DEBUG] 15703 Mojolicious.Plugin.RequestTimer - POST /admin/node/save (Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1).
[2012/07/24 14:06:09] [DEBUG] 15703 Mojolicious.Routes - Routing to a callback.
[2012/07/24 14:06:09] [DEBUG] 15703 Mojolicious.Routes - Routing to controller "MyApp::Admin" and action "save".
Wide character in print at /home/nikita/perl5/lib/perl5/Log/Log4perl/Appender/File.pm line 245.
Wide character in print at /home/nikita/perl5/lib/perl5/Log/Log4perl/Appender/Screen.pm line 39.
[2012/07/24 14:06:09] [DEBUG] 15703 MyApp.Admin - 123123!!!11������������������
```

**Update 2:** I am using Morbo as development server, and my application layout contains `meta` header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

**Update 3:** Strange, but *sometimes* the string is encoded and displayed correctly:

```
[2012/07/24 14:55:52] [DEBUG] 16451 Mojolicious.Routes - Routing to a callback.
[2012/07/24 14:55:52] [DEBUG] 16451 Mojolicious.Routes - Routing to controller "MyApp::Admin" and action "save".
[2012/07/24 14:55:52] [DEBUG] 16451 MyApp.Admin - 112!!ЫВафывафывп
[2012/07/24 14:55:52] [DEBUG] 16451 Mojolicious.Plugin.RequestTimer - 302 Found (0.326543s, 3.062/s).
[2012/07/24 14:55:52] [DEBUG] 16451 Mojolicious.Plugin.RequestTimer - GET /admin (Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1).
```

and if I do the same thing second time, I get:

```
[2012/07/24 14:57:30] [DEBUG] 16451 Mojolicious.Routes - Routing to controller "MyApp::Admin" and action "save".
Wide character in print at /home/nikita/perl5/lib/perl5/Log/Log4perl/Appender/File.pm line 245.
Wide character in print at /home/nikita/perl5/lib/perl5/Log/Log4perl/Appender/Screen.pm line 39.
[2012/07/24 14:57:30] [DEBUG] 16451 MyApp.Admin - 112!!��������������������
[2012/07/24 14:57:30] [DEBUG] 16451 Mojolicious.Plugin.RequestTimer - 302 Found (0.362417s, 2.759/s).
[2012/07/24 14:57:30] [DEBUG] 16451 Mojolicious.Plugin.RequestTimer - GET /admin (Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1).
```

Comment: [Show your code](http://sscce.org) so that we may [reproduce the problem](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html#showmehow).

Comment: What code do you need? There's too many potential failure points.

Comment: Produce a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org). If you a poor programmer and not capable to do so, provide everything: all your code and example data to run the code with. - [UTF-8 in SQLite/DBIC works fine for me.](http://codepad.org/ryXtKEGW)

Comment: See the question update.

Comment: Is your web-page and server configured correctly? Check the encoding is indicated both in the header and the `meta` tag.

Comment: Why are you not showing us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed

```
% use utf8;
```

from one of the templates, and after that text is displayed as it should.

Answer (score 1):

The "wide character in print" warning makes me think that your output filehandle isn't expecting to see utf-8 characters.

The [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) manual page explains Perl errors and warnings in more detail. Here's what it says about this warning.

> **Wide character in %s**
>
> (S utf8) Perl met a wide character (>255) when it wasn't expecting
>   one. This warning is by default on for I/O (like print). The easiest
>   way to quiet this warning is simply to add the :utf8 layer to the
>   output, e.g. binmode STDOUT, ':utf8' . Another way to turn off the
>   warning is to add no warnings 'utf8'; but that is often closer to
>   cheating. In general, you are supposed to explicitly mark the
>   filehandle with an encoding, see open and binmode.

I suspect you would also benefit from reading the [Perl Unicode Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) (and chapter 6 of the [4th edition of the Camel book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do)).

Comment: I don't think it's relevant: these warnings are produced by Log4perl appenders.

Comment: You may be right. But it indicates that you have utf-8 data *somewhere* in your system. Try telling the appenders to expect utf-8 data and see what changes. And the rest of my advice still holds true. There's a lot you can get wrong when dealing with utf-8 data. Read the documentation.

Comment: I've looked at my templates again and I found '% use utf8;'. Removing it resolved the issue.